# subqueries throwing an error

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have the following subqueries, and they are throwing an error

```
 select ts.id,(CONCAT(ts.first_name, ' ', ts.last_name),
 (    select SUM(hours*pay)

   from 
 PTAddedApp aa 
   where 
   aa.tutor_id = ts.id
   and year(aa.date) = year(now())
   and month(aa.date) = month(now())


 ),
 (select SUM(nt.hours*nt.rate)
   from PT_NT_Work_Hours nt 
   where 
   nt.tutor_id = ts.id
   and year(nt.date) = year(now())
   and month(nt.date) = month(now())
 ) 

 from PT_Tutors ts
```

I get the following error message. I assume that I am doing something daft-
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from PT_Tutors ts' at line 21

I posted a similar questions to see if I should use joins instead, and they pointed me back to subqueries, so I'm hoping someone can let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open 2 brackets near your concat function but only close 1. Remove the bracket before 'CONCAT'

```
select ts.id,CONCAT(ts.first_name, ' ', ts.last_name),
 (    select SUM(hours*pay)

   from 
 PTAddedApp aa 
   where 
   aa.tutor_id = ts.id
   and year(aa.date) = year(now())
   and month(aa.date) = month(now())


 ),
 (select SUM(nt.hours*nt.rate)
   from PT_NT_Work_Hours nt 
   where 
   nt.tutor_id = ts.id
   and year(nt.date) = year(now())
   and month(nt.date) = month(now())
 ) 

from PT_Tutors ts
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure almost everyone has found themself breaking their head over these errors at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be this.

```
SELECT  ts.id,
        (CONCAT(ts.first_name, ' ', ts.last_name),
        aa.totalAddedApp.
        nt.totalNT
FROM    PT_Tutors ts
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT tutor_id, SUM(hours*pay) totalAddedApp
                FROM PTAddedApp
                WHERE  year(`date`) = year(now()) and 
                    month(`date`) = month(now())
                GROUP BY tutor_id
            ) aa ON aa.tutor_id = ts.id
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                select tutor_id, SUM(hours*rate) totalNT
                from PT_NT_Work_Hours
                where  year(`date`) = year(now()) and 
                    month(`date`) = month(now())
                GROUP BY tutor_id      
            ) nt ON nt. = ts.id
```

Comment: John Woo - If I may ask, what do I gain by using a Join? I really don't understand them, though I have tried to figure them out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before the CONCAT you open a parenthesis you're not closing :

```
select ts.id,(CONCAT(ts.first_name, ' ', ts.last_name),
```